# Почему документация HTTP/2 рекомендует использовать TLS?

Tags: tls, http2

В одной из книг прочитал, что некоторые прокси-сервера могут не явно пропускать через себя веб трафик. Так же эти прокси-сервера могут не распознавать http2, далее дословно :

> Из-за такого поведения новые протоколы и расширения HTTP, такие как
> WebSocket, HTTP / 2 и другие, должны полагаться на создание туннеля
> HTTPS для обхода промежуточных прокси-серверов и обеспечения надежной
> модели развертывания: зашифрованный туннель скрывает данные из все
> посредники

Как HTTPS туннель помогает скрыть посредников ?

Comment: `https` не скрывает посредников, а скрывает данные от них, т.е. гарантирует, что посредников или нет или они ничего не увидят

Comment: https сейчас вообще везде рекомендуют использовать. Chrome в особенности, и многе другие популярные производители браузеров сговорились, и сделали максимально неудобным использование сайтов без https. Они светятся как гарантировано небезопасные, а хром ещё скачку файлов блочит.

Comment: Инкапсулирование HTTPS в HTTP можно считать туннелем ?

Comment: Да, потому что tls и есть тунельный протокол. Тунелирование - чаще всего представлено двумя видами: 1) паковщики, 2) шифровальщики. Когда один поток данных превращается в другой поток данных из которого можно сделать исходный.